# load Mathjax after loading javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

here is my simple `HTML` code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<script>
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the line that load correct  \[ \frac{x+y}{z} \]</p>
<p id="step1"></p>
<script>
var x = gup('x');
var y = gup('y');
var z = gup('z');
var text = "This is the line that NOT show correct" + "\[ \frac{" + x + " + " + y + "}{" + z +"}\]";
document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML= text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I load this html file and send parameters by url like

```
sample.html?x=1&y=2&z=3
```

the first sentence shows correct form and load `Mathjax` but the second sentence NOT. it is because `Mathjax` load before the java script code. do you know how to load `Mathjax` after `Javascript`?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a JavaScript loader with a callback to load MathJax and run your code in the callback.
See https://github.com/niftylettuce/javascript-async-callback for example.

EDIT:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
  var x = gup('x');
  var y = gup('y');
  var z = gup('z');
  var text = "This is the line that NOT show correct <-- It's OK now" + "\\[ \\frac{" + x + " + " + y + "}{" + z +"} \\]";
  document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML= text;
});
</script

</head>
<body>
<p>This is the line that load correct  \[ \frac{x+y}{z} \]</p>
<p id="step1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Who exactly didn't worked? It throw some error maybe? Please paste the code you wrote to test it.

Comment: I added this line on header <script src="//raw.github.com/niftylettuce/javascript-async-callback/master/async.min.js"></script> and after the javascript part of body i added <script>
 (function liveDemo() {
 var src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js'
 function callback() {
    alert('It works!')
 }
 _async.load(document, src, callback)
 }())
 </script> but it not eve show me the "alert" did I inserted in wrong place?

Comment: You're supposed to use the library I have you but write your own code, not just copy/paste the demo :s . Anyways, I just tested your code and it works properly. What's the exact problem? Because I can see all the variables that are parsed from the location.

Comment: yes variables are in the place it is not my problem, after inserting them i should re run mathjax to show them in formula way. because mathjax run before java the variables will not show in proper way

Comment: sorry for copy pasting the demo but if the demo even would work i could see the alert and after that i should mix it with my code. am i right?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 3):

If you modify the document to add mathematics after MathJax has run, you need to tell MathJax to run again.  You do that using

```
<script>
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
</script>
```

See the [relvent MathJax documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/typeset.html) for details.

In your case, this should do it:

```
<script>
var x = gup('x');
var y = gup('y');
var z = gup('z');
var text = "This is the line that NOT show correct" + "\[ \frac{" + x + " + " + y + "}{" + z +"}\]";
document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML= text;
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"step1"]);
</script>
```