# Displaying ascimath using javascript

Tags: javascript, asciimath

Created a html with

```
<div id="math-display">   </div>
```

Next, on the main.js, retrieve from the database using ajax and pass the data which are in asciimath using json.mathanswer.  The aim is to display the return data which are in asccimath as mathematical expression.  For example: data retrieved from database is ***dy/dx = 3*x^3***.  Passed to json.mathanswer.

Have tried using the following code:

```
$('#math-display').append(json.mathanswer);
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#math-display').textContent =json.mathanswer;
```

The display is still in asciimath, i.e. ***dy/dx = 3*x^3***.

Also tried using the delimiters:

```
$('#math-display').append(`json.mathanswer`);
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#math-display').textContent =`json.mathanswer`;
```

The result is ***json.mathanswer*** will be displayed in the space allocated.

How to display the ***asciimath*** retrieved as data in mathematical expression html using javascript?

Comment: In general, the ASCIIMath fails to render as equation, and the ASCIIMath source code is displayed instead.  Only ASCIIMath that is present in HTML renders properly and not the one generated by javascript. Can anyone suggest a way around it?

Comment: Still on the same problem.  Came across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652568/javascript-mathjax/20829634#20829634.  Guess my problem is the same with that?  Where do I insert that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the facts that many have come across and posted on stackoverflow.  Thank you for all those clues.

For instance:

[Javascript Mathjax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652568/javascript-mathjax)

[load Mathjax after loading javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621491/load-mathjax-after-loading-javascript?rq=1)

The html for the parts that the asciimath code resides needs to be refresh after loading the input from ajax call.
Thus calling the following code to reload after loading the ajax call.

In my case,
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "expression"]);
did the job in displaying the mathematical expression.